# 'var' is not defined in 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.x

This is a code example from book:

```
width, height = 240, 60
midx, midy = width // 2, height // 2
for xen in range(width):
    for уen in range(height):
        if xen < 5 or xen >= width - 5 or уen < 5 or уen >= height - 5:
            image[xen, yen] = border_color
        elif midx - 20 < xen < midx + 20 and midy - 20 < уen < midy + 20:
            image[xen, yen] = square_color
```

When I try to run this, I get error: 'yen' is not defined. But it was defined in 'for' loop, and so 'xen' was defined. I know that the book I am reading is kind of old, but I don't understand why am I getting this error and how to avoid this. I know there are loops, but this code seems fully legit to me. What's the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I copy and paste your code, the `y` in `yen` in your for loop is an odd character (maybe a [Cyrillic 'U'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A3)). It looks like a `y` but it's not. Try retyping the line:

```
for уen in range(height):
```

These look the same, but if you run the snippet, you'll see they aren't:

```js
console.log("уen" == "yen")
```

Comment: You are right. That's weird as I am only on the US layout. Thanks for the answer.